# Why worship something you cant see?

Tags: religion

I'm an atheist, just to be clear.  So it makes sense to me that you'd want to see or touch something before you worship it.   We are all in awe if we are so lucky as to see an alien spacecraft. And some even luckier people have said they touched them.  And some claim to have even been aboard the spacecrafts.    So , why not worship these crafts?   But then again, the whole idea of worshipping something seems alien to me.  John Lennon really had it right with, "Imagine no religion."

Comment: You will get better answers if you post this question on Philosophy.SE. And I think there must already be several answered questions along your question.

Comment: No, I think it's important to take the question to the people.   To get them thinking.

Comment: Iit's fine to get people thinking but this is not exactly what SE sites in general and Islam.SE are about. See http://islam.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: As a matter of fact,  it has nothing to do with Islam.  You can ask this to any religion

Comment: @makzimus perhaps OP wanted to see how would Muslims attempt it.

Comment: I could ask it to any religion,  but I'm asking it here.  Aren't you lucky?

Answer (score 4):

*I will try to answer your question from numerous angles. This is from the Shia perspective.*

**Angle 1:**

Say you're American living in Seattle, but it was the year of 1890, where there was no television.

The country is working as it should, I mean everything is being done right on clock. Taxes are collected, roads are made, everyone is being vaccinated, government is providing education, etc & etc.
Do you ever say I have to see the president to know he exists? Or Simply by seeing the results of his presence you know there must be a president governing the country?

Same thing for our universe! The sun is going back and forth like a clock, does the sun ever say I am changing night to 1pm? Or is it somehow being guided? 
The earth is orbiting in a very precise manner around the sun...If earth was not orbiting in such a precise manner, then some parts would have been either too cold or too warm. You might just it's because of gravity, but who placed gravity there?

**Angle 2:**

Do you see pain? Do you see jealousy? Do you Love? Do you bigotry? Do you see cowardness? do you see humility? Do you see kindness?

Can you show inside a person's heart?! No! Yet you believe it exists. Can't you believe the same for the person who has control above you?!

**Angle 3:**
When you look into yourself, do you see yourself in 100% full control of yourself? Or is it that sometimes you are happy but then suddenly you become sad, Or is that sometimes you are sad, but you suddenly become happy.

This a debate between Imam Sadiq & a atheist who became a believer.

> "Woe unto you! He Who has shown you His power in yourself, how has He
>   hidden Himself from you? He has created you while you were nothing,
>   made you grow up while you were a child, made you strong while you
>   were weak. Now, think of your illness after your health, your health
>   after your illness, your pleasure after your anger, your anger after
>   your pleasure, your sorrow after your happiness, your happiness after
>   your sorrow, your love after your hatred, your hatred after your
>   love.... He (al- Sadiq) went on mentioning Allah's favors which are in
>   myselfand which I cannot deny. So, I thought that He (Allah) would
>   appear between him (al- Sadiq) and me."

**Angle 4:**
Just see this link [here](http://www.imamreza.net/eng/imamreza.php?id=386)

Comment: To add in your *angle 2*, here's my question *Why breathe air when you can't see?*

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question.

... ...

One premise of the Qur'an, is that there are forms of knowledge which human beings are not "entirely" aware of. That being said, knowledge of reality could be said to exist on a continuum, of which there are infinite degrees.

For example: human beings have gained progressive knowledge about the molecular structure of our world. Who would have known, prior to the technology being available, that the pin of a needle would contain about a million million atoms?

Indeed, from my experience, it is possible that, the closer we look on a molecular level, the more we will discover. The Qur'an hints at this, when it says (interpretation of the meaning):

"He Who created the seven heavens one above another; no want of proportion wilt thou see in the creation of (God) Most Gracious. So turn thy vision again; sees thou any flaw?" (Sura Al-Mulk, v. 3).

... ...

Also, if you are interested, then there is a significant amount of evidence, both in the Qur'an and in the Hadeeth, that there are many (potentially infinite) forms of life, including beings such as aliens.